# How to stop the speech syntheziser?

Tags: .net, speech, .net-3.0, synthesizer

How do I STOP the System.Speech.Synthesi.Syntheziser? There are build in methods for pausing and resuming,but I don't see how to totally stop the engine. when I use the SpeakAsyncCancel method the state property indicated that the Synthesizer is still speaking.

Do I have to use threads or do I not understand?.

Comment: Is this a Windows thing? A .NET Windows thing?

Comment: the speech class is part of the .net framework.

Comment: That's pretty unclear, the SpeakAsyncCancel() method requires a Prompt argument.  You didn't document what you used.  Use SpeakAsynchCancelAll() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured it out after some goggling. The Synthesizer is multi-threaded, therefore they must only be ONE instance in the program, so make a static one somewhere with a static constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SpeakAsyncCancel` you need to pass a prompt parameter, for example:

```
Synthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancel(new Prompt("cancelling now"));
```

You can use `SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` as well, and finally dispose:

```
Synthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
Synthesizer.Dispose();
```